# Android Studio XML closing tag indentation

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have a TextView defined as

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Semita"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        />
```

But I don't like the closing tag on the same indentation level as the attributes. When I hit backspace I'd like it to look like:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Semita"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    />
```

which is what I'd like, I instead get:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Semita"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>
```

where the `/>` is on the same level as the attributes. How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the cursor before the `/>` and press `Shift + Tab` if you are using Mac.

Pressing Tab adds 4 spaces and pressing Shift + Tab moves 4 spaces back.

Comment: Will I have to do that for every tag? I'm looking for an option specifically so I can apply this to all of my XML files.

Comment: There is an option in Preferences > Editor > Code style > XML > Tabs and spaces > Continuation Indent. If you change the value of continuation indent to 0, you wont get space before the closing tag when you press enter. But on the downside you wont get the indentation for the android attributes at start.

Answer (score 1):

There is **auto-indentation** if you have already your closing tags, simply press "Ctrl+Alt+I".  This will auto-indent whatever block you are highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML** and select **Android** tab
In Layout Files section **check "Insert line break after last attribute"**[image]

Answer (score 0):

While Bob's answer should solve your problem. You should consider following this format:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Semita"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

see

```
Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML
```

for xml formatting & indentation

[image]

**but you should use node starting and full ending tag for this**

there is no option to move short closing node tag to new line with current ide options instead use

```
// node 

<tag attr="val"            //  starting tag
     name="alalala">      
    i'm body               //  tag body  
</tag>                     //  closing tag
```

or post your issue here with feature request

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: Can you point on the option that I'd use? I know to look there, and I've tried all those options but none of them do what I'd like.